# Blockchain.info unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, blockchain.info

I'm a newbie and was wondering what to do when there is an unconfirmed transaction on Blockchain.info. Can I reverse the transaction? Will my BTC reach the other side? Or are they lost?

Comment: Do you mean that you made the transaction using blockchain.info's wallet, or that you look at the transaction using blockchain.info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your transaction doesn't confirm, and the sender (blockchain.info/wallet, in this instance) doesn't re-broadcast the transaction then the transaction should disappear from your wallet, as if it had never been made.

This may take a day or so.

If the transaction is being re-broadcast by the sender then it can stay there as long as the re-broadcasts are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on unconfirmed it will show the progress of the transaction. I notice I am a little late replying (you posted 3 hours ago) it should have completed by now if you check again.